# .htaccess is rewriting to files in root of my server, not current directory that .htaccess is located in

Tags: .htaccess, server

I am trying to create some nicer URL's instead of the file names and want to do it with .htaccess

But my url is being rewritten to the index.php in the root of my server, not the directory I am working in.

Why is that?

My htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase /

#Indexes uitzetten
Options -Indexes

#Cross site access toestaan
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"

#CMS rewrite
#RewriteRule ^cms/$ /cms/administrator [L]

#All-Tek

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteRule         ^home index.php [L]
RewriteRule         ^info/(.*)$ content.php?alias=$1 [L]
RewriteRule         ^(.*)$ catlisting.php?alias=$1 [L]

#ErrorPages
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.php
ErrorDocument 501 /error/501.php
ErrorDocument 503 /error/503.php
ErrorDocument 504 /error/504.php
```

`home` should show me the index.php of the current directory that I am working in (and where my .htaccess is located) but instead it shows me the index.php in the root of my server which is a few directories back. Why?

Comment: Where is that .htaccess located?

Comment: @Valdars In the folder that I am working in, I have a server with multiple folders that contain websites, my htaccess is in one of those folders.